# Is there an excel function to find the preceding non zero number from the max value in a row

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX4g9.png)

In this case 51

Comment: There is no function of which I am aware. You can probably write a formula, or a VBA User Defined function, to do that.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld Could you provide me with a direction on the formula

Comment: What have you tried? I'd probably use `INDEX, MATCH, LOOKUP`. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the help. I had clearly asked only for a direction, not the code

Comment: Those references will be handy if you run into a roadblock.  Also, I should have mentioned you'll need the `MAX` function also.

Comment: =IF(Q14=1,0,IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-1)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-1),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-2)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-2),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-3)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-3),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-4)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-4),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-5)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-5),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-6)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-6),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-7)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-7),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-8)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-8),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-9)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-9),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-10)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-10),IF(INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-11)<>0,INDEX(C14:N14,Q14-11),0))))))))))))

Comment: Q contains the coloumn number of the max value

Answer (score 0):

That works, but I'd do a bit shorter by using arrays.

- Name the range of interest `Rng`

  - In your case, refers to `C14:N14`
- Find the `MAX` value; use `MATCH` to get the column in the `Rng` and subtract 1

  - `MATCH(MAX(Rng),Rng,0)-1`
- Create an array from that value:

  - If you have the `SEQUENCE` function:  `SEQUENCE(MATCH(MAX(Rng),Rng,0)-1)`
  - If you don't:  `ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(MAX(Rng),Rng,0)-1))`

    - `{1;2;3;4;5;6}`
- `LOOKUP` the last non-zero value in that array:

Putting it all together:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/INDEX(Rng,0,SEQUENCE(MATCH(MAX(Rng),Rng,0)-1)),Rng)
```

or

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/INDEX(Rng,0,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(MAX(Rng),Rng,0)-1))),Rng)
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/INDEX(Rng,0,N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(MAX(Rng),Rng,0)-1))))),Rng)
```

and "confirm" this **array-formula** it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*